# regular expressions to strip h3 tag and leave the content

Tags: regex, coldfusion

im looking for a regex to strip the h3 tag and only the content should remain

eg.

`<h3 id="123">my h3 tag</h3>`

i need to strip the tag and be left with

> my h3 tag

im currently have `reMatchNoCase("(<h3)(.*?)(</h3>)",i)`

this was parsed from many other parts of a string, not i need it cleaned to the content

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<cfset content = ReReplace(content, "</?[hH]3[^>]*>", "", "ALL")>
```

This should be faster than ReReplaceNoCase, and still be case insensitive (because of the `[hH]`).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really use regexen to parse HTML, but it you want to here's a quick hack:

```
/<\s*h3[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h3>/
```

Just replace this with $1.

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace

```
<h3[^>]*>
```

and

```
</h3>
```

with nothing.